# Checking for overflow and/or carry flags, getting an integer code of which happened

Tags: assembly, x86, integer-overflow, carryflag, signed-overflow

First, I want to point out that this isn't really x86, it's msx88 which is a sort of simplified version of x86 for learning purposes.

I need to make a function that checks for arithmetic errors (carry, overflow) and I know that I can use `jo` and `jc` for checking, but the problem is returning back to the point after the check (I don't want to use call, and I am not sure if jumps store IP, so I don't know if I can use ret).

How can I modify my code so that I can execute JO, and if it makes the jump, so that it return to the next instruction after JO (JC)?

```
ORG 3000H 
ArithmeticError: MOV AX, 0 
JO overflow
JC carry
RET ;Return 
overflow: ADD AX, 1
carry: ADD AX, 2


;If overflow AX=1, if carry AX=2, if overflow and carry AX=3, else AX=0
ORG 2000H
CALL ArithmeticError

END
```

Comment: Thanks everyone for your responses, didn't expect such quick replies, and I learned a thing or two about how to think of a problem before tackling it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should save the flags before any arithmetic. Something like

```
  MOV AX,0 ; NB not XOR to keep flags intact!
  JNO no_overflow
  PUSHF ; save flags
  INC AX
  POPF ; restore them back for the second check
no_overflow:
  JNC no_carry
  ADD AX,2
no_carry:
  ; if AX is zero, we have no error
  TST AX
  JZ out
  CALL ArithmeticError
out:
  RET
```

Comment: While the msx88 instruction set does not include TST, I like the approach to managing the negations of the cases, I even get the bonus of being able to try and figure out how to replace TST.

Comment: You could `pushf` / `pop ax` / `and ax, 0x0801` to isolate the two bits you want inside FLAGS.  Also, `inc` leaves CF unmodified, so you don't actually need to save/restore FLAGS if you test CF second.  Or start with `lahf` to get CF into the bottom of AH, before doing something with OF (which is unfortunately outside the low 8 bits of FLAGS).

Comment: As @Aviar says, there is no `TST AX` in normal x86 either.  Perhaps you meant `test ax,ax` to set FLAGS according to it.

Answer (score 1):

You actually just want to `call ArithmeticError` with AX= one or two bits right?  The returning-from-JO is just an X-Y problem in your implementation.

There are a few strategies you can use.  On simple one is to get FLAGS into AX and test the two bits there. (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FLAGS_register has the layout).  We can leave it to `ArithmeticError` to sort out the bit positions in the rare case we actually have an error, instead of doing extra work every time.

```
   pushf
   pop    ax           ; OF = 0x0800  CF=0x0001
   and    ax, 0x0801   ; zero the other bits, leaving only OF and CF
   jnz    ArithmeticError      ; tail-call / jump  if either were set
back:
   ret

ArithmeticError:
; at the start of ArithmeticError, if you want to shuffle 0x0801 to 0x03
   shr    ah, 2        ; 0x8 -> 0x2
   or     al, ah       ; AL = 0 0 0 0 ' 0 0 OF CF.    (AH can be non-zero)
   ... do your printing or whatever
```

Jumping to `ArithmeticError` lets it use our return address, not coming back to us.  (This is an **optimized tailcall**.)  Otherwise in the common case, `jnz` falls through so we reach our own `ret`.  It comes out the same as doing this, because `call foo`/`ret` is equivalent to `jmp foo`.

```
   ...
   jz    no_error        ; equivalent without optimized conditional tailcall
   call ArithmeticError
no_error:
   ret
```

---

`inc` leaves CF unmodified in x86.  I'm assuming that's also true in msx88.  That could be useful if we ever wanted to use `inc ax`; `inc ax` to increment by two.

But `mov` doesn't touch FLAGS at all, so we can just `mov ax,2` if we're more interesting in simplicity than code-size<sup>1</sup>.

```
   mov  al, 0
   jno  no_overflow
   mov  al, 2         ; AL = 2 if OF was set
no_overflow:
   adc  al, 0         ; AL += 0 + CF, setting the low bit or leaving unmodified
   jnz  ArithmeticError   ; use FLAGS set according to AL, by ADC
   ret
```

**Footnote 1:**  `inc ax` is a 1-byte instruction in 16-bit mode, vs. 3 for `mov ax, 0` or `mov ax,2`.  When optimizing for ancient 8088 CPUs, you would use `inc ax` twice (2 bytes total) instead of `add ax,2` (3 bytes) because code-fetch was the primary bottleneck.

But to save bytes, we used `al` instead of `ax`.  You can zero-extend into AX if you want in the `ArithmeticError` case, or change the instructions to use AX directly.

---

If we have [`setcc`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/setcc) (386 and later), we can turn a FLAGS condition into an integer 0 / 1 in a register.  Without it, you might start with 8086 [`lahf` (Load AH from FLAGS)](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/lahf) to get CF into the bottom of AH, before doing something with OF (which is unfortunately outside the low 8 bits of FLAGS).  `lahf`/`and ah,1` emulates `setc ah`, except it also writes FLAGS so you'd have to wait until after branching on OF.

```
; kinda clunky
   setc   ah     ; AH = CF      ; optionally use CL or DL to avoid partial-register stalls or false dependencies
   seto   al     ; AL = OF
   add    al, ah    ; AL = 1 or 2 if either or both bits were set
                    ; we'll have to decode using AH to recover which one
   jnz   ArithmeticError   
   ret

; assuming that no-error is vastly more common than either carry or overflow
; we made the branching as cheap as possible, leaving more decode work for this
 ArithmeticError:
   sub  al, ah      ; undo the add, back to AH=CF, AL=OF
   shl  ah, 1
   add  al, ah      ; CF + 2*OF
 ; if I'd used separate regs like dl and al, could have used  lea eax, [eax + 2*edx]
```

#### Somewhat efficient assuming errors are rare: two not-taken branches

```
   jo   overflow
   mov  al, 0         ; only zero AL if mov al, 2 isn't going to run
   jc   carry
   ret

overflow:
   mov  al, 2
   jnc  nocarry      ; alternative:  ADC al,0  as in the earlier version
carry:
   inc  ax           ; like OR al,1   since AL=0 or 2 before this
nocarry:
   jmp   ArithmeticError       ; could be a call, if you want to put stuff after
```

This ends up checking CF in two places, but that's because we want to keep the fast path as minimal as possible, just two not-taken branches.  (And a `mov al,0`).

**You could take this even further and do more work sorting things out in the `overflow:` and `carry:` blocks, so the fast path is just `jc` / `jo`.**  So the `carry` block can't assume any register state was already set up.  You might just use both halves of AH:AL separately.  If errors are rare, the extra code required will still run a negligible amount of times.

But if you're replicating this for every operation that you want error checking for, it makes sense to tighten it up.

Putting the `mov al,0` between the two branches spaces them out, which may help branch predictors in some CPUs.  Maybe not important if they're usually both not-taken.  But may help on in-order pipelines, especially P5 Pentium which can pair `jcc` in the V pipe ([See Agner Fog's microarch guide and instruction tables](https://agner.org/optimize/)).  (`ret` is not pairable, but near `call` is.)  Of course modern x86 does out-of-order exec, but producing correct predictions for dense branches can still be a problem for the front-end.

We're *not* depending on an a conditional-tailcall, so we can use `ArithmeticError` if we want to inline this block into functions instead of having a `ret` after the `jc`.  Also, so even before 386 `jcc rel16`, we aren't limited to a [-128,+127] branch displacement to reach `ArithmeticError` with `jcc rel8`.  JMP *does* have a 16-bit displacement version even in 8086.

Answer (score 0):

A JMP does not preserve the calling address.

If you don't want to do a CALL, I would store the result somewhere, do your other processing, and then make the call (or do the same function within the current procedure).

It's not clear why you don't want to use a call, but a call is the best operation to use if you want to return to where you called it from.

Comment: In fact, what I'd probably want to do is do JNC and then the call. If the carry is set, it won't jump and you'll make the call. And then, after the call returns you'll continue on as if nothing has happened. If the carry is not set, it'll jump over the call.

Comment: Got it. I simply altered it so that the JC check appears again after the JO jump to overflow, and a RET after the new JC check in case the new check fails. If the new check succeeds, then it jump to carry, in which case I simply add a RET afterwards to complete the function. In the case that neither the original JO or JC jumps are taken, it simply returns with the 0 in AX.

Comment: Just read what you wrote Jonathan, for the sake of learning, I'll try your way out. It seems more elegant, but let me see if I got it straight, add in a JNC before CALL, nop after call. Elegant idea.

Comment: It would look similar to the code grep suggested. I was thinking of using a call because I wasn't clear if you wanted to perform other tasks. But if you just needed the single link, them my idea would be the same.

Answer (score 0):

If you dont want to use call, you can push the modified IP onto stack, use the JMP and then use RET. Below is pseudo code:

```
PUSH [IP] +x ; [where x is the size which would evaluate to instruction just after POP IP]
JO OVERFLOW
ADD SP, y  ; y is size of address. if jump was not taken
XOR EAX,EAX  ;the IP of this instruction minus orginal IP would be x


OVERFLOW:
; program instructions
RET
```